# How to separately access the abscissa and ordinate of the current point?

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom
    {
        \psline(1,0)
        \rlineto(0,1)
        %\translate(!!CP.x 0) % does not work!
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to separately access the abscissa and ordinate of the current point, how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CP is actually a postcript macro of two elements `x y`.
You can access them using `pop` and `exch pop` to access them separately.
However the values are not in the same coordinate system as the pstricks coordinates (eg. `(1,2)`) so some conversions are necessary. 
Here it goes

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom
    {
        \psline(1,0)
        \rlineto(1,1)
        \rlineto(!!CP pop -2 \pst@number\psyunit mul) %CP.x = 2 --> \rlineto(2,-2) 
        \rlineto(!!CP exch pop -1 \pst@number\psyunit mul) %CP.y = -1 --> \rlineto(-1,-1)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is: 
[image]

Comment: `\rlineto(! CP \tx@UserCoor pop -2 )` makes life easier ...